# how to perform xor cipher in matlab

Tags: matlab

i have a plain text message:hello world and a key :hidden.I want to perform xor encrytion and decryption.i convert the characters to binary form.and then perform the xor encrytion using the code xor(plaintext,key),it shows an error message dimensions not matching.

How to perform xor ciphering in matlab using the repeating key?/////

Answer (score 1):

Just repeat the key (using `mod`) to the appropriate size. Here is the basic operation that works if you already have a binary representation of the `key` and `plaintext`:

```
xor(plaintext, key(mod(0:numel(plaintext)-1, numel(key))+1))
```

However, normally you would thus want to use `bitxor` as you are handling string inputs.

```
plaintext = 'hello world'
key = 'hidden'
plaintext = char(bitxor(plaintext+0, key(mod(0:numel(plaintext+0)-1, numel(key+0))+1)+0))
```

You will find that if you run the last line again (with your new plaintext result) you get the original message back.

---

**Alternate method** (in case you really want to use xor)

This is how you could input the `plaintext` and `key` as strings, and get out the encryption result as a string.

```
%Set the string and keystring
plaintext = 'hello world';
key = 'hidden';

% Translate your string into a logical vector
plaintext = reshape(dec2bin(plaintext,8),1,[])-'0';
key = reshape(dec2bin(key,8),1,[])-'0';

% Execute the xor operation
result = xor(plaintext, key(mod(0:numel(plaintext)-1, numel(key))+1));

%Return the result
result = char(bin2dec(char(reshape(result + '0',[],8))))'
```

Of course we want to make sure we have not made a mistake, so therefore the following test:

```
% Now the test whether we can decrypt it
plaintext = result;
plaintext = reshape(dec2bin(plaintext,8),1,[])-'0';
result = xor(plaintext, key(mod(0:numel(plaintext)-1, numel(key))+1));
result = char(bin2dec(char(reshape(result + '0',[],8))))'
```

Comment: Figured it out, hope you don't mind the extensive edit.

Comment: Of course not! But why didn't you post an answer? You deserve the merit. At least include a note in this answer to show which part (most all now) is yours